# Is marginal probability of default the same as conditional probability of default?

Tags: risk, default-probability

I'm thrown off by the term marginal probability of default. I've seen it defined by some authors as synonymous term for conditional probability of default

**conditional probability of default:** probability of defaulting given no default yet.

Which is solved for as such:

$PD_{conditional} = \frac{P(default\_anytime\_before\_period\_t1) - P(default\_in\_period\_t0)}{1-P(default\_in\_period\_t0)}$

I've also seen it defined as:

> The default time density function or marginal default probability is
>   the derivative of the default time distribution w.r.t. t:
>
> $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}P[t^*<t]=F'(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$

Where

$t^*$ is the time of default

$t$ is the point in time we are observing from

$\lambda$ is the hazard rate

$F(t)$ = cumulative default time distribution = $P[t^* <t] = 1-e^{-\lambda}$

**Question**

Does this mean that $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ is an approximation of the conditional probability of default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your definition, they are certainly not the same. Generally, the marginal default probability is the probability that the default happens in a given time period, such as $[t, t+\Delta]$, that is, $P(t < \tau \le t+\Delta)$. Here, $\tau$ is the default time. See Chapter 10 of the book [Counterparty Credit Risk and Credit Value Adjustment](http://www.amazon.ca/Counterparty-Credit-Risk-Value-Adjustment/dp/1118316673) for definitions.
Note that
\begin{align*}
P(t < \tau \le t+\Delta) &=P(\tau \le t+\Delta) - P(\tau \le t) \\
&\approx \Delta \frac{\partial P(\tau \le t)}{\partial t}.
\end{align*}
Then, people treat the marginal default probability, over a small time period, as the density $\frac{\partial P(\tau \le t)}{\partial t}$.

However, the conditional default probability is defined by
\begin{align*}
P(\tau \le t_1 \mid \tau > t) &= \frac{P\big((\tau \le t_1) \cap (\tau >t)\big) }{P(\tau >t)}\\
&=\frac{P(\tau \le t_1) - P(\tau \le t) }{1-P(\tau \le t)},
\end{align*}
for $t_1 > t \ge 0$.

Let $t_1 = t + \Delta$, for $\Delta$ sufficiently small. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\Delta} P(\tau \le t + \Delta \mid \tau > t) &= \frac{P(\tau \le t + \Delta) - P(\tau \le t) }{\Delta \big (1-P(\tau \le t)\big)}\\
&\approx \frac{1}{1-P(\tau \le t)} \frac{\partial P(\tau \le t)}{\partial t}\\
&=-\frac{\partial \ln \big[1-P(\tau \le t)\big]}{\partial t}\\
&=\lambda.
\end{align*}
In fact, the hazard rate is formally defined by
\begin{align*}
\lambda = \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} P(\tau \le t + \Delta \mid \tau > t).
\end{align*}

In literatures, the terms may be misused. Then, we need to pay attention to the specific definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Could you explain what "marginal probability is the density of the default time τ" means? Much appreciated.

Comment: That is from your original text, as you said "the default time density function or marginal default probability ...".

Comment: Sorry yes I realize that, could you explain what it means?

Comment: Generally, the marginal default probability is the probability that the default happens in a given time period, such as $[t, t+\Delta]$, that is, $P(t < \tau \le t+\Delta)$. As this is close to $\Delta \frac{\partial P(\tau \leq t)}{\partial t}$, people treat the marginal default probability, over a small time period, as the density.

Comment: Oh ok, I *think* I get it. The cumulative (aka unconditional) probability is the probability default occurs between $t - \tau $ for example between years 1 and 5. The marginal probability would be the probability of it ocuring in a specified year... assuming nothing about possible previous defaults.

Comment: Yes. We can say that the marginal default probability over year 4 is the probability that the default happens in year 4, that is, $P(3< \tau \le 4)$, while the cumulative default probability to year 4 is $P(\tau \le 4)$.

Comment: As a minor quibble, there is good reason to prefer a different definition of the hazard rate as the [generalized derivative](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_derivative) of the cumulative default probability, consistent with measure theory in general.

Comment: Thanks @BrianB. It can be defined as a general hazard process.Here, I tried to be simple.